# System.StackOverflowException when Displaying a usercontrol in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, user-controls

I have a usercontrol in Silverlight which display a tree of items and lets you select and search in these items. When this component gets displayed I get a stack overflow exception. The problem is, non of the stack traces Visual studio shows me is part of my code. the recursive call seems to happen somewhere in the framework code, somewhere at:

```
System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(...)
MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.InvalidateProperty(...)
```

as far as Visual Studio can tell me.

Has anybody a idea what the problem is, or a better way of debugging this problem?

Comment: Did you override the `InvalidateProperty` in the user control?

Comment: Have you checked that there are no circular references in your object hierarchy, i.e. some item has itself as a child or a parent as a child?

Comment: Hi Michael, no I didn't. Have some Dependency Properties there and some code behind to build up the treeview

Comment: Problem even occurs when there is only one element in the treeview, but maybe there is a circular reference elsewhere, i'll try to check that, thanks